# How to cover up this vent at the bottom of my windshield?

Tags: fan, air-filter

Here's the part that I am trying to describe:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C0ENDk_zll0cBa9aoRKwI5QgCKMQRRuB/view?usp=sharing

Why I would like to cover this up is because my car is parked outside and there's small leaves coming through this part of the car. Then when I turn on the blower, it spits out leaves.

I would like to cover it with finer mesh to prevent small leaves from coming through my fans.

I think what I need to ask is, what is the purpose of that vent. Can I cover it up completely? If I can't cover it up completely, what can I use to cover it up just to prevent small leaves from coming in.

Comment: The purpose of the vent is to vent the cowl space, which is where most cars gets the air to circulate into the cabin. If you close it off ... no more fresh air.

Comment: but how come newer cars don't have this vent? if that's the case then I can't fully block this vent. I guess I gotta go the hardware store instead of the car shop to find a good mesh that I can use that can also fit

Comment: If you are trying to keep stuff out of there, try gluing screen to the underside. Itll still let air through without allowing the stuff. Just a thought.

Comment: "but how come newer cars don't have this vent?" they do, its just not where it use to be, hidden behind the front fender most likely.